# CsQuery Issue: TypeLoadException was unhandled

Tags: c#, csquery

I have created a new console app and installed CsQuery via nuget in order to write an app to scrape some HTML.

Any time I try to use CsQuery such as:

```
CQ dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://google.com");
```

I get a "TypeLoadException was unhandled" error as below:

[image: mscorlib.pdb not loaded]

I have searched on SO and the posts I have read have said this is due to an error in my code but all I have done is copy a basic example snippet to see how it works. Is CsQuery not installed correctly?

Comment: The error message says: "Could not load type 'CsQuery.CQ' from assembly

Comment: oops, it changed after I selected some options.  I will edit.

Comment: Are the .NET versions the same? Is your project running with .NET Client Mode?

Comment: The project was targeting .net 4.5.  I changed to 4.0 and tried again but same error.

Answer (score 1):

OK this was frustrating but ultimately stupid on my part.  I named the project CsQuery so there was a naming clash.  I created a new project with different name and it worked.  Took me far too long to figure it out :S